# Unable to use unicode in outputfile name for FFMPEG transcode

Tags: ffmpeg, c#

I am using FFMPEG in a **C#** windows service to convert videos. Conversion is working fin. But when I specify the outputfile name containing unicode, transcoding fails. Is it a known issue, or is there any way to make FFMPEG support unicode characters?
This is the parameters I use for conversion:

> ffmpeg.exe -i "*inputfilePath*" -y -s 640x360 -b:v 1024k -r 29.7
>   -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p "*outputfilename.mpg*"

It will fail when I use unicode in "outputfilename"

**Edit:**
I am submitting these values from C# code, not from windows console. Do I need to pass anything additional to support unicode? I need to support complete Unicode character set, as the output name can be in any language.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an ffmpeg problem, it is your windows console that is not set to use Unicode. to change the code page to Unicode type at the command prompt:

```
chcp 65001
```

and change the console font to a Unicode one (e.g. Lucida Console, but it doesn't contain a complete Unicode character set, you need to find one that has the characters of your specific language).

Comment: Hi avnr.. thanks for the response. I am submitting these values from C# code, not from windows console. Do I need to pass anything additional to support unicode. I need to support complete Unicode character set, as the output name can be in any language. Thanks

Comment: In that case your situation is good because you don't care about the font, you just need to change the code page. When you spawn the ffmpeg call you can prepend it with the code page change: `chcp 65001 && ffmpeg...`